# how to collect the heap info when the Go program is killed through the cgroup way?

Tags: go

I am running a Go process under a cgroup with an OOM Killer, and I want to print the heap memory info by such as command "go tool pprofhttp://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap" or any other way which can figure out the top memory consumers when the process is killed (Btw, it is better to print the heap info by the Go process itself  such as call some method by the Go process), so I can know top memory consumers and fix it next time.

Comment: How would it create a heap profile if it has no more memory with which to do so? Also, the kernel is going to send a SIGKILL, so there's nothing you could do at that point anyway. You need to profile your program under the same load before it gets killed.